# Which python Linux IDEs support GAE's webapp2 framework?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ide, webapp2

I am a newbie in the world of python and I want to change that. So far all my projects have in done in text editors like gedit, but for my final I need to do something more complex and I actually want a tool that helps me do it and that does not get in the way.

My final project is a dynamic website in GAE using the webapp2 framework. My objective is to find a free python IDE that supports that.

So far, [after checking some of the options in the wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments),  my search is stalled:

- PyCharm supports webapp2, but only in the professional version
- Komodo only has addons for Django

I was wondering, if anyone out there knows of a good IDE (with auto-completion at least) that supports webapp2, or that has some really good plugin for doing that and that it is free (no trial versions please)

I understand this question may have multiple possible answers, but I would really appreciate any possible help here. Kudos++ will be given to the most promising answers as usual.

Comment: eclipse with pydev to. This is a good article with complete details about the installation and first GAE app:[see this link](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-python-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much deliberation, I tested Eclipse with the pydev plugin, and the trial version of pycharm. I decided to go with pycharm, as it is better **in pretty much everything**.